# Get all n-size combinations with k-size letters list

Tags: php, algorithm

Could anyone help me? I am trying find formula and write piece of code in PHP language which makes next

Imagine, we have 3 types of something, k = 1,2,3 and length of this numbers could be various (n-length), but neighboring type should not(!) be the same - 1,1 or 2,2

For example
k = 1,2,3
n = 5

Output
1,2,3,1,2 |
1,2,3,1,3 |
1,2,3,2,1 |
1,2,3,2,3 |

1,3,2,1,3 |
1,3,2,1,2 |
1,3,2,1,3 |
1,3,2,3,1 |
1,3,2,3,2
.........

Mb this is has some common named problem, share with me pls and I'will try to find some resources about

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Also see [mcve] and [homework](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of generation such lists is recursive (if n, k are not large -note that variant count is k*(k-1)<sup>n-1</sup>).

Pseudocode:

```
Generate(list, n, k, lastvalue)
    if (list.length = n)
          output(list)
    else
          for i = 1 .. k
              if (i != lastvalue)
                  Generate(list + i, n, k, i)
```

Delphi code

```
procedure Generate(list: string; n, k, lastvalue: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
    if (Length(list) = n) then
          Memo1.Lines.Add(list)
    else
          for i := 1  to k do
              if (i <> lastvalue) then
                  Generate(list + IntToStr(i), n, k, i)
end;

begin
  Generate('', 4, 3, 0);
```

Output for n=4, k=3

```
1212  1213  1231  1232  1312  1313  1321  1323  
2121  2123  2131  2132  2312  2313  2321  2323
3121  3123  3131  3132  3212  3213  3231  3232
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont know how its gonna work, I had tried implement this and programm stop with memory leak

Which would be the last value in first function call??

Comment: Take 0. I could show Delphi code if this will help.

Comment: sure pls show me if u can, I was learning Delphi when I was a student

Answer (score 0):

well u do a loop in a loop. since k has a length, and the numbers in the k variable are the ones you move along, they present the outer loop. (for loop)
now u can run along the output because u have the number n known as well.
u place k[1] as the first variable of n[1] and it doesn't change until the inner loop is over. (in this case k[1] is 1). now u do a while loop with a changeable (a for example) variable that runs over the n array created. n will be (1,null, null, null, null). while a != n.lenth(). u check the n(a-1) for it's value to make sure is not the same. whenever a reaches n.length, u change the value of the last number by the next on the k array, and then you go back 2 spots (n[a-1]) and change it and go back, go recoursive all the way to the start until all spots have been changed and the n[2] of the array has the highest value of the k array. to make life easier, u can make a new array, let us assign as j for the matter, which will get a value as soon as the closest n[a] spot gets the last value possible.

BTW whenever u go  back reset the value of spots u ran by to null so that all the numbers in the k array are optional again. when the j array is full, you reset all of it and move on in the for loop.

hope i was of help, if you have any questions feel free to ask